# How to match a date pattern in strings

Tags: python, regex, date

I am trying to **match any number of correct format dates** in a given string. For a date to be in correct format, it has to appear in the form dd-mm-yyyy. Therefore dd and mm cannot have just one digit, they need 2 and they need to be in the correct range; this means that day has to be between 1 and 31 and month has to be between 1 and 12.

I have it working for one type of input, but it does not match another input.
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sys import stdin
from re import compile

myFormat = compile(r'(?=([0-2]\d|3[0-1])-(0\d|1[0-2])-(201[3-5]))' )
print myFormat.findall(stdin.readline())
```

**Input 1:**

```
777-444---21-12-2013-12-2013-12-2013---444-777
```

Output:

```
[('21', '12', '2013'), ('13', '12', '2013'), ('13', '12', '2013')]
```

So far so good. But if I have the input:

```
0012-10-2012-10-2012
```

it matches nothing. The correct output is supposed to be:

```
[('12', '10', '2012'), ('12', '10', '2012')]
```

Please help me find the correct regex to do this

### EDIT

**I only want to match only years 2012 to 2015.**

Comment: Is it important if the date is actually valid? `31-02-2013` will be a positive match here.

Comment: yes it is because I want to match only valid dates which is why I was using range of numbers instead of "\d"

Comment: If that's the case, you should try to convert the matches with `datetime` to make sure the dates correspond to actual calendar dates and not just a bunch of numbers that match your pattern.

Comment: I guess my new question now is how do I use datetime?

Comment: Overlapping dates implies checking for a date _range_, but the actual problem is search for a date _pattern_ withing a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your regex to:

```
myFormat = compile(r'(?=([0-2]\d|3[0-1])-(0\d|1[0-2])-(201[2-5]))' )
```

it will work (just change last `[3-5]` to `[2-5]`). Currently it doesn't because you have:

```
201[3-5]
```

for the year part, so it refuses to match 2012.

For checking validity:

```
from sys import stdin
from re import compile
from datetime import datetime
myFormat = compile(r'(?=([0-2]\d|3[0-1])-(0\d|1[0-2])-(201[2-5]))' )
str1=("0012-10-2012-10-2012", "0031-02-2012");
for s in str1:
    for date in myFormat.findall(s):
        (d,m,y) = map(int, date)
        try:
           datetime(y,m,d)
           print date
        except: pass
```

Comment: I don't think this will match a date in 2016.

Comment: I don't think either. So OP wants to match all possible dates? 1976 also?

Comment: I believe so since the pattern is `yyyy`? Ah, nevermind - seems OP has a specific range.